Dynamically create Mapping of various types
I have different animals
enum ANIMAL_TYPE {
    dog = "dog",
    cat = "cat"
}

interface CommonAnimalProps {
    animalType: ANIMAL_TYPE
}

interface Dog {
    common: CommonAnimalProps
    breed: string,
    alive: boolean
}

interface Cat {
    common: CommonAnimalProps
    origin: string,
    height: number,
    furious: boolean
}

In the future, there will be more of them. I want a dynaic type definition that respresnt the following map (let's call it AnimalTypeToAnimalMapping)
{
    ANIMAL_TYPE.dog: Dog[],
    ANIMAL_TYPE.cat: Cat[],
}

So that whenever there is another animal in ANIMAL_TYPE, I also get another entry with its corresponding type in AnimalTypeToAnimalMapping. I have tried this
type AnimalTypeToAnimalMap = {
    [K in keyof typeof ANIMAL_TYPE]: { common: { animalType: typeof ANIMAL_TYPE[K] } }
};

export type AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType = {
    [K in keyof typeof ANIMAL_TYPE]: AnimalTypeToAnimalMap[typeof ANIMAL_TYPE[K]][]
}

Background: I want to use lodash'es groupBy function and then iterate through the result like this
const dog1: Dog = {
    common: {
        animalType: ANIMAL_TYPE.dog
    },
    breed: "pudel",
    alive: true
}

const cat1 = {
    common: {
        animalType: ANIMAL_TYPE.cat
    },
    origin: "EG",
    height: 20,
    furious: false,
}

const variousAnimals = [dog1, cat1];

const [groupedAnimals, setGroupedAnimals] = useState<AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType>(groupBy(variousAnimals, "common.animalType"))

But this gives me

TS2345: Argument of type
Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]>
is not assignable to parameter of type AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType | (() => AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType)
Type Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]>
is missing the following properties from type AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType: cat, dog

Here is Playground
Why?

Your problem is that groupBy returns Dictionary<T>, you can see the implementation here.
So when you call groupBy, you get a Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]>:
groupBy(variousAnimals, "common.animalType"); // Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]>

Then when you pass it to useState<AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType> you will get an error:
const [
    groupedAnimals,
    setGroupedAnimals
] = useState<AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType>(
    groupBy(variousAnimals, "common.animalType") // ERROR
);

This is because the types AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType and Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]> are not compatible.
import { Dictionary } from 'lodash';

// ...

declare var x: Dictionary<(Dog | Cat)[]>;
declare var y: AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType;

x. // <-- no autocomplete suggestions
y. // <-- suggestions for x.cat and x.dog


Your best option is probably to create a wrapper around groupBy:
const variousAnimals = [dog1, cat1];

function groupVariousAnimalsBy(path: string): AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType {
    return groupBy(variousAnimals, path) as any;
}

const [
    groupedAnimals,
    setGroupedAnimals
] = useState<AnimalsGroupedByAnimalType>(
    groupVariousAnimalsBy("common.animalType") // OK
);

